# Which gcc pass optimizes the value of variables away

Tags: gcc

When compiling with gcc optimization. Some values of variables are optimized out.
Does anybody know which gcc pass optimizes the variables value out, so that I can disable such pass to keep the variables unoptimized?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `-fdump-tree-all` and check the dump files produced... But essentially you should use -O0 if you don't want optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but you should probably take a look at flags such as `-fssa-backprop`. According to the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> Propagate information about uses of a value up the definition chain in order to simplify the definitions. For example, this pass strips sign operations if the sign of a value never matters.

This optimisation is turned on at level `-O1` (and any higher levels of optimisation as well).